# Centos 7 curl HTTPS error (1)

Tags: https, centos7, curl, php7

### The curl error

```
# curl https://www.google.com
curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

### Background info

I start listing my specs:

- CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

`# curl -V curl 7.61.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.61.1 Release-Date: 2018-09-05 Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp  Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile UnixSockets`

```
# curl-config --configure
 --with-ssl
# curl-config --ca

# curl-config --features
IPv6
UnixSockets
AsynchDNS
#
```

I have some certificates (i just searched .crt files XD) in these locations:

- /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl
- /etc/pki/ca-trust/source
- /etc/pki/tls/certs
- /tmp/curl-7.61.1/tests/certs
- /usr/share/pki/ca-trust-legacy
- /usr/src/ca-certificates/etc/pki/tls/certs
- /usr/src/ca-certificates/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-legacy/

I read (and I can't find it anymore) about problems in certificate from centos 6 to centos 7.

I installed everything from yum, nothing from source.

Am I missing something?!

Comment: A problem perhaps?

Comment: There's not enough info in the question to be able to form an opinion. Perhaps show what you are running and the resulting error might help.

Comment: Do you need more information? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

```
which curl
```

gave me "/usr/local/bin/curl", and this is not what I expected, so i checked if /usr/bin/curl was working correctly, and it was.

I just checked if something was using this curl, `rpm -qf /usr/local/bin/curl` and as expected nothing was using it, so I just deleted /usr/local/bin/curl and now everything work properly.